# Lost sessionvariables in firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

I have a pretty strage problem im dealing with.

Lost sessionvariables in firefox.

Im using wordpress and have a subpage that causes the loss. 
More specific:

In wordpress there exists a page called *My pages* (Original page names are in swedish, translated for convinience)
Under this page i have a few subpages. Among these are a page called *Create test*. There is nothing special about this page, for now only contains the phrase "hello world". If I enter any page other that this, it works. 
But this particular page just seems to clear my session variables (wich I use to store login info)

I tried deleting the page in question in the effort to remake it.
While it was deleted I tried navigating around on the page.

Create test was the last item in the subnavigation menu, and now when its gone, the same thing happens on the last menuitem (now *Account settings*). This leave me to believe its something with the menu.

Even more strange, after recreating *Create test*, so that this page is now the last item. Still it's *Account settings* that is the page with the resetting of sessionvars...

I have through `echo` determined that the session id stays the same, just the variables that get `unset`.

I have `unset($_SESSION['id']);` at only one place, and this code is NOT run.

The problem just baffles me and I have no idea why this particular pages does this.

Comment: Is this specific to firefox? Are the session cookies deleted?

Comment: tested in IE,Chrome and safari and all is well. ITs the same session so i believe the cookies are still there. Just the variables that get lost

Comment: How do you test that variables get unset?

Comment: ordinary `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see that the vars is gone and `echo session_id()` to see that the session is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now, actually have no idea what I did. but I've change some html but mostly CSS.

So there is a strong posibility it was CSS-related.

Answer (score 1):

It may be totally unrelated, but we had problem with Firefox and sessions on certain pages in the past. It happened most of the times while developing and therefore refreshing a particular page, have you tried clearing your browser cookies which is where session is stored?

As an addition:

Check that you assign sessions before you write anything to the response stream.
Also we had similar problems with sessions set in a pages that were doing a redirection (i.e. a login page that if successful would set the session and redirect to the another page.) 
I'm not sure about PHP but in .NET that can be overcome by explicitly setting not to terminate the response so that all headers are written to the response stream.

Comment: Must have been the problem, seems like it was fixed after a full clear :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, seems that the problem is back after the cookies got set again :|